# Best Approach for Uploading and Displaying Images in a AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is the best approach for Uploading and Displaying Images in a AWS S3 Bucket?

```
1.
Frontend <--> Backend <--> S3 Bucket
(Image shall be sent to backend, backend shall internally upload to S3 bucket)
                or
2. 
2.1 Frontend <--> Backend <--> S3 Bucket
    Frontend shall request for temporary URL of S3 Bucket
2.2 Frontend <--> S3 Bucket
    Frontend shall upload images/files using that temporary URL.

3. Any other??
```

Comment: can you describe what benefit you see in the 2-step solution? If not, one-step would always better than two-step. Maybe it would be helpful to show code for both

Comment: 1. Delegating Image Upload responsibility to Frontend. 2. Less workload on server side. 3. Decoupling Access granting responsibility to Backend & Upload responsibility to frontend. 4. Ofcourse comparatively less AWS billings, as images/files. Please correct if my analysis is wrong.

Comment: OK. I don't see how any of these benefits can be achieved. Maybe if I saw the code alternatives. Frankly, I don't understand what you mean by 2.1 - *temporary* URL. Assuming that the name of the region, bucket and (optionally) parent directories is static - Frontend can generate the URL of the file quite easily.

Comment: @Felix, Do you suggest #1 even when the files are large (i.e ~1G)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on frontend/backend technologies. In a project, I used Reactjs(frontend) and Node.js(backend). It was pretty smooth uploading images to s3 bucket in nodejs using aws sdk.

So I would prefer Frontend <----> Backend & Backend will use aws sdk to upload images to S3 bucket.

Helpful link to upload images in S3 buckets using Node.js: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-node-examples.html

Comment: Do you suggest #1 even when the files are large (i.e ~1G)?

Answer (score 0):

Frontend <--> S3 Bucket    // with in angular-12 or 13//

Frontend shall upload images /view images in using that temporary URL with in angular

```
please shar your answers i hope using in some peoples 

thank you
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).